# Textbook for graduate analysis over a general complete valued field?

Tags: analysis, reference-request

At my university, the standard sequence of first-year graduate analysis courses is taken by students who plan to go into analysis, differential equations, and applied math. These students know why they have to learn analysis. The first-year graduate analysis courses are also taken by students who plan to go into algebraic topology, algebraic number theory, and algebraic geometry. These students sometimes are disinterested in learning classical analysis (over the real or complex numbers), because their perspective is not yet broad enough to see the fundamental importance of analysis and/or how it is related to the subjects they plan to specialize in. My efforts to explain to these students why they ought to care about analysis have generally not been successful.

My colleagues and I are considering the possibility of running our first-year graduate analysis courses as courses in analysis over a general complete valued field. Over the archimedean fields, we would recover classical analysis over the real and complex numbers; over the non-archimedean fields, we would recover many cases of interest to the students who plan to study algebra, particularly analysis over p-adic fields. We hope the resulting courses would be of interest and of use to all our students. But it is not yet clear to us that this idea makes sense; perhaps some topics (e.g. integration theory) are simply too different in the non-archimedean case to treat them, at this level, alongside the classical treatment.

There are many good references on functional analysis which work over non-archimedean fields, or which allow the base complete valued field to be archimedean or non-archimedean. However, I do not know of a graduate analysis textbook (not just functional analysis, but rather roughly the contents of a standard first year of graduate analysis) which works over a general complete valued field. Do you know of any such textbook? Thanks.

Comment: I think most graduate students find graduate measure/integration theory more than sufficiently challenging working with the concrete cases of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$. Sometimes generalizing too soon makes for terrible pedagogy. But it’s an interesting twist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by analysis you meant functional analysis, then the book that comes to my mind is ***Functional Analysis and
Valuation Theory*** (1971) by L. Narici, E. Beckenstein, and G. Bachman. The preface of that book states:

"...Generally it would be accurate to say that we have tried to present functional analysis over arbitrary valued fields, and to best benefit from the book, the reader should be familiar with some classical functional analysis and some valuation theory"

It might be worth your time to take a look at it.